# Нужна помощь с библиотекой Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Помогите пожалуйста с моим кусочком кода на python:
По задумке, код из себя представляет 2 функции-команды: первая просто отправляет в чат то, что отправили после >repeat, а вторая является рекурсионной и получает на вход аргументы, нужные для 1 функции и выполняет её, используя все нужные для нее аргументы.

```
@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

@bot.command()
async def comand(ctx, *, arg):
    await repeat(ctx, arg)
```

Тем не менее, при вызове второй функции появляется ошибка: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: repeat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Попробовал записать вторую функцию следующим образом:

```
@bot.command()
async def comand(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.repeat(arg)
```

Но стала вылазить другая ошибка: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'repeat'`

Пожалуйста, помогите кто - чем может, заранее всех благодарю :3.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать, что вам нужно, чтобы происходило после ">repeat", а на счет второго вопроса, вообще не понял, что вы хотите сделать, возможно вам поможет статья на Хабр: https://habr.com/ru/articles/676390/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите вызвать из команды совсем другую команду, то это работает не так, как вы хотите. Вообще не так.

Есть [специальный метод](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke) для вызова других команд. По логике это должно работать следующим образом:

```
@bot.command()
async def first(ctx: commands.Context, *, arg1):
    await ctx.send(arg1)


@bot.command()
async def second(ctx: commands.Context, *, arg2):
    await ctx.invoke(first, arg1=arg2) # Аргументы после * считаются кваргами
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам, помогли на 101%. Ваш ответ очень исчерпывающий, и даже я - новичок смог сделать то, что задумывал. Изначально я не знал про метод invoke и думал, что функцию можно вызвать просто как в обычном python: f(arg), то есть не нужен ни print, ни присваивать значение, а просто вызвать без присвоения.